# How to set libgit2 instead of git.exe in tortoisegit?

Tags: tortoisegit

when I settings use libgit2. but it always remind me to set git.exe path.
I want to use libgit2 to replace git.exe for data upload, can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TortoiseGit requires a git.exe in any case, because not all functonality is provided by libgit2 or implemented.

If you want to use the experimental libgit2 functions, you have to adjust a DWORD value in registry (HKCU\Software\TortoiseGit\UseLibgit2_mask). Setting it do DWORD_MAX (0xffffff) it will enable all implemented libgit2 functions in TortoiseGit.